# Kак понять это перегруженный оператор в двусвязном списке? И зачем здесь проверка на тип записи в файл

Tags: c++

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator << (ostream& ustream, LinkedListParent<T>& obj) {
if (typeid(ustream).name() == typeid(ofstream).name()) 
{
    ustream << obj.num << "\n";
    for (Element<T>* cur = obj.getBegin(); cur != NULL; cur = cur.getNext())
        ustream << current->getValue() << " ";
    return ustream;
}
```

Comment: Что-то этот код вызывает больше вопросов, чем ответов...

Comment: ахахаххаха ну тут не поспоришь

Comment: просто главное, не понятно, что это за проверка if (typeid(ustream).name() == typeid(ofstream).name())

Comment: Непонятно, зачем (это *попытка* проверки, что реально передана ссылка на файловый поток), и зачем так, гм... странно. "Странно, если не сказать больше" (с)